When updating fiji's StackReg plugin to 2.0.1, a different plugin breaks with "Unrecognized Command : StackReg" when attemping to call macro
I'm using an unofficial plugin for fiji that used to work fine for the past ~4 months.
However this morning I've found that FIJI has a new update. Following this update, my attempts to call the StackReg macro
    IJ.run(x, "StackReg", "transformation=[Rigid Body]");

throws an error Unrecognized Command : "StackReg".
After some searching I've discovered that StackReg has updated to version 2.0.1 from 2.0.0 which seems to somehow cause this. Reverting back to 2.0.0 works fine, however I've been unable to successfully recompile and install the plugin to allow it to detect StackReg 2.0.1 and I keep running into the same error.
I fully admit I'm not at all experienced with Maven or gradle so it's very possible I've incorrectly set something up, but it's unclear to me if the plugin's unable to see the newer StackReg version or if the syntax for Stackreg's macro has changed in the update.
My pom.xml file. Everything enclosed with //NOTE is my attempt at comments.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        
    <groupId>cirb</groupId>
    <artifactId>Ovocyte_nucleus_Analyze</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>plugins/CIRB/Ovocyte_nucleus_Analyze.jar</name>
    <description>
            Analyse variations of nuclear envelop during time 
        </description>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>phm</id>
            <name>Philippe Mailly</name>
            <email>philippe.mailly@college-de-france.fr</email>
            <url></url>
            <organization>CIRB, Collège de France</organization>
            <roles>
                <role>developer</role>
            </roles>
            <timezone>-1</timezone>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/imagej/Ovocyte_nucleus_tracking</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:imagej/Ovocyte_nucleus_tracking</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
        <url>https://github.com/pmailly/Ovocyte_nucleus_tracking</url>
    </scm>

    <properties>
                <imagej.app.directory>/opt/Fiji.app/</imagej.app.directory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <main-class>Ovocyte_nucleus_tracking</main-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.imagej</groupId>
            <artifactId>ij</artifactId>
                        <version>1.54f</version> //NOTE: I've changed this from 1.51g
                        <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>

//NOTE: I believe I added these two dependencies and the two relevant jars in the src/main/java/Ovocyte/tools/ folder.
     <dependency>
      <groupId>ome</groupId>
      <artifactId>bioformats_package</artifactId>
      <version>6.9.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>sc.fiji</groupId>
      <artifactId>MTrack2_</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>

//NOTE: I added this to try to fix my current issue.
     <dependency>
      <groupId>sc.fiji</groupId>
      <artifactId>StackReg_</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
        <id>imagej.public</id>
        <url>http://maven.imagej.net/content/groups/public</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>jitpack.io</id>
                <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    <build>
            <finalName>${project.artifactId}_${project.version}</finalName>
            <plugins>
        <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
        </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copytoplugins</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                   //NOTE truncated for my privacy
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Changing the version for sc.fiji.StackReg_ to 2.0.1 brings me to a compilation error. On further searching I've found a Maven Repo page that claims StackReg_ was never updated since ver 2.0.0 or 2014.(unable to post it since I'm being marked as spam?)
Am I missing a different repo that I should be using instead or is this expected being a new update and it'll somehow fix itself soon? I'm currently working around this by using a local version of StackReg_.2.0.0 and not updating the plugin when asked.
Thank you.

What you are writing is in many respect confusing. There is absolutely no need to compile the plugin StackReg because it is part of Fiji and, if necessary, will be updated by using "Help >> Update...". Furthermore, what do you mean by "Stackreg's macro". I have no idea what "an unofficial plugin" could be because there are neither official nor unofficial plugins for ImageJ/Fiji. Last, I recommend to download a fresh Fiji and activate or install the plugins you need. If this doesn't work as expected, then please post again and perhaps less wordy and more to the point.

By Stackreg's macro, I mean this part from the BIG update site:
"""StackReg is scriptable and recordable. Here is an example of a call to StackReg from a macro:
run("StackReg ", "transformation=[Rigid Body]"); """
In my plugin sourcecode, I use this macro to run StackReg on an image of mine. Up until the recent 2.0.1 update, I have not had any issues with this. I'm not sure if the 2.0.1 changed the syntax for this, or if my plugin's simply not seeing the newer version of StackReg which I cannot point to in the pom.xml as Maven's sc.fiji repo does not have a StackReg 2.0.1.

For reference this is the plugin I'm attempting to use.
https://github.com/pmailly/Ovocyte_Nucleus_Analyze (was unable to post it on the original post as it marked it as spam)

I can't test plugin StackReg (current version: 2.0.1) because I don't have sample images to do so. If, after a fresh download of Fiji, your macro-problem persists, I'd contact the author[s] of this plugin (presumably Daniel Sage). Furthermore, I recommend to always update ImageJ "Help >> Update ImageJ..." to the current version (presently: 1.54k).
